# Cleaner nested for loops in Cython without losing efficiency

Tags: python, for-loop, cython, indentation

I'm writing optimized code in Cython that operates on a grid and often end up with constructions like this:

```py
for i in range(n_boxes[0]):
    for j in range(n_boxes[1]):
        for k in range(n_boxes[2]):
```

Sometimes, there are even more nested `for` loops within the innermost loop.

The Pythonic way to avoid such ugly constructs would be something like

```py
for i, j, k in itertools.product(*(range(n_boxes[dim]) for dim in n_boxes)):
```

but Cython can't optimize this into C `for` loops, which are much more efficient than calling out to Python, constructing tuples, unpacking tuples, etc.

How can I avoid the ugly nesting in the first example, and the excessive indentation that goes with it, while still allowing Cython to compile the code to a set of nested C `for` loops?

Comment: are `n_boxes[...]` by chance degrees of 2? Also, what do you use them for (there might be other special properties to exploit)?

Comment: @Marat: unfortunately `n_boxes` are derived from the input data and thus can be anything.

Comment: Personally three loops looks pretty clear (OK, there's indentation, but the intent is obvious) while I find the itertools version pretty hard to read at a glance. I don't know of an obvious way of translating the itertools version to (efficient) Cython.

Comment: @DavidW: The issue comes when this is already inside an `if`, and has three more loops inside... the nesting gets extreme but I don't want to add function calls by refactoring it, since these are very much critical inner loops. Maybe an inline function is good enough though.

Comment: The only thing I can really think of is something similar to https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html (although you'd probably want to write your own as a cdef function rather than use Numpy's if you're worried about performance)

Comment: @DavidW: I see what you're saying... I've already implemented those functions, so it's an interesting idea.